# Select those data where data in either one column or 2 column are same

Tags: mysql, r, dataframe

I have below mentioned data in Database:

```
ID      V1   V2
1       A    B
2       A    B
3       A    C
4       X    Y
5       W    V
6       R    V
```

Desired output: (Where value in either V1 or V2 or in both are same.)

```
ID     V1    V2
1       A    B
2       A    B
3       A    C
5       W    V
6       R    V
```

In addition, after getting the output is there any way in `Mysql` or `R` to Add a status column which show me which value was duplicate either `V1` (if `V1` was duplicate), `V2` (If `V2` was duplicate) and `Both` (if `V1` and `V2` both was duplicate.

Desired output: (Where value in either V1 or V2 or in both are same.)

```
ID     V1    V2  Identifier
1       A    B   Both
2       A    B   Both
3       A    C   V1
5       W    V   V2
6       R    V   V2
```

Comment: Where is your query? which you have tried ?

Comment: @HamzaZafeer `select ID, count(V1,V2) as c from table
group by ID having c > 1
order by c desc`

Comment: and what are the results which your are getting now? also please share those results, and update your question.

Comment: @HamzaZafeer getting some error.

Comment: which error ? also post the error and complete your question. now it is totally unclear what you wants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.v1 = t.v1 and t2.id <> t.id) or
      exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.v2 = t.v2 and t2.id <> t.id) ;
```

Comment: Is there any way to add a Status column to know which value matched as duplicate. (i.e if `V1` match than status "V1" for `V2` status "V2" and for both status "Both".

Comment: @VectorJX . . . You can move the logic to the `select` and use `case`.  If that is not obvious, then you can ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select distinct same.id, same.v1, same.v2 from same 
join(
    select V1 as v, count(V1) as c from same group by V1 having count(V1) > 1  
    union
    select V2 as v, count(V2) as c from same group by V2 having count(V2) > 1
) a on a.v = same.V1 or a.v = same.v2
```

Comment: Your query seems right but don't know why it's not working....i want only those `id` where i found either `V1` or `V2` or both duplicate in the date base.